# Adding query import to Android Studio JetPack Compose -Kotlin project

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to get the data from the emulator contact list.

I added to Android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Then in the Code :

```
val cursor = ContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
```

But for some reason I can not import the query function and I cn not underatnd why.

Any ideas?
Thanks

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Mwk.jpg)

Comment: i think you should handle run time permission. refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765277/read-contacts-permission-not-working

Comment: @sasikumar thank you for your answer but I'm not sure it is going to help . I added image of my problem to the question. Even when I'm pressing the first import it does not add the import and query() is still red.

Answer (score 0):

`ContentResolver` is an abstract class .You cannot create object for it .And query is an instance method in ContentResolver (Not static method - which you have tried as shown in image).

For accessing content resolver object with context or applicationContext.

```
val contentResolver  = context.contentResolver // or val contentResolver  = applicationContext.contentResolver
val cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
```